# How to handle Lua memory/references if my userdata is used as a key elsewhere?

Tags: lua, garbage-collection, lua-table

I am indexing some table with my userdata (lets call it Turret) - to store some associated variables like bullets and armor.
I need to manage Turret's lifecycle by being able to set it to nil, subsequently allowing Lua to GC it. I'm worried that I lose all control over the object's memory when I use it as a key elsewhere.

Sample Code:

```
local turretStorage = {}

-- Bunch of turrets are created and added, lets look at the one below

local turret = load.newTurret(15) -- Create a Turret userdata
turretStorage[turret] = {}
turretStorage[turret].bullets = 100
turretStorage[turret].decal = "skulls.png"

-- Some time passes, we're done with the turret object
turretStorage[turret] = nil
turret = nil
```

My concern is the indexing of turretStorage by turret userdata. Does turret userdata ever get GC'd? If setting the turretStorage[..] to nil removes the key references - could you please show me supporting documents?

Should I somehow nil the key in the turretStorage table? If so, how would I do it?

If the key is used as a reference of the original variable and can't be removed, then I am stuck and need help, or refactoring.

If the key in this example is just userdata's memory location used as a unique index - then I'm completely in the clear; but - the answered question would have references to support this ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object in Lua is only considered garbage and marked for collection when there are no references to it inside Lua. Using a value as a key in a table counts as a reference.

Consider also using [weak tables](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.5.2) if they fit your design.

Comment: Thank you lhf, I restructured my code to use unique IDs for objects and I "key" them that way. Sorry for taking so long to reply - do you know of any ways to un-reference a table key?

Comment: @Kaa, to remove a key from a table, just sets its value to nil. Consider also using [weak tables](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.5.2).